# Xstring Problem with Ş

Tags: xstring

I want to use xstring version 1.7.  However ş and ç cause problems. For instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\StrSubstitute{ş}{a}{b}

\end{document}
```

creates a long list of errors like this one:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \@xs@arg@ii.
```

I am using the encoding package with the utf8 option and other characters like ö, ü and ğ are fine.

Edit: Here is the mwe  spelled out in full.

Comment: Please show us an MWE. We need this in order to help you. Thanks.

Comment: This is a problem with `pdflatex`, but works fine with the utf8 engine `lualatex`.  Can you switch to that instead?

Answer (score 3):

Package `xstring` uses `\edef` to expand the arguments by default, then commands can break like the UTF8 character.

The expansion mode can be changed, e.g. `\noexpandargs` to prevent expansion at all. It can be used inside a group or the expansion mode can be saved and restored afterwards:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\saveexpandmode
\noexpandarg
\StrSubstitute{ş}{a}{b}
\restoreexpandmode

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Why I don't have a problem with i, ö, ğ and ü then?

Comment: @user2955390 - With utf8, many glyphs use 1 byte (8 bits) for encoding, whereas others need 2, 3, or even 4 bytes. You're "discovering" that `i`, `ö`, `ğ` and `ü` need just 1 byte, whereas `ş` and `ç` need more.

Comment: @user2955390 It depends, how these letters are implemented with the current input encoding. Some are robust inside `\edef`, some not.